# How to avoid this javascript eval()?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to rid my code of a couple of `eval`s that I have in my javascript, but I'm not sure of the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do.

I have a "filter form" on a bunch of my pages, with a bit of JS attached to it that reloads parts of the page depending on what the user does.

Different pages require different actions though.

So my solution (that I came up with yearrrrs ago...) was

```
<form name="callback_loadCalendar">
<form name="callback_loadNames">
```

Etc.

And this horrible bit of JS (attached to onchange events etc) to then call the relevant function:

```
if (f.getAttribute('name') && f.getAttribute('name').indexOf('callback') === 0)
    eval(f.getAttribute('name').substr(9)+'()');
```

E.g. that would call `loadCalendar()` and `loadNames()` respectively.

What SHOULD I be doing instead?

Thanks!

Comment: The question is, *when* is that code executed? It seems you could just attach the correct function to the form's onsubmit event.

Comment: Possibly, though not as concisely/simply I don't think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the functions are in the global scope, then you can use bracket notation in the global scope to access the function references.

```
window[f.getAttribute('name').substr(9)]();
```

Comment: Perfect, and so simple, thankyou!  I assumed I'd have to do some major recoding on all fronts to achieve this in a completely different manner.

Comment: Ah, and if they're not?  Will this work if they're all wrapped in an IIFE?  It should do, I suppose?

Comment: @Codemonkey in that case you can do something like `var callbacks = {loadNames: function(){}, loadCalendar: function(){}}`, then `callbacks[f.getAttribute('name').substr(9)]();`